# How to make terminal open another terminal window that runs a command

Tags: raspbian, lxterminal

I'm working a raspberry pi project including Alexa Builtin (https://github.com/alexa/alexa-avs-sample-app/wiki/Raspberry-Pi). Everything is working but the startup script I'm working on

```
#! /bin/bash

lxterminal -e "cd companionService && npm start" &
lxterminal -e "cd javaclient && mvn exec:exec" &
lxterminal -e "cd wakeWordAgent/src && ./wakeWordAgent -e sensory" &
```

but when I run it, I get this

```
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open '/home/pi/Desktop/alexa-avs-sample-app/samples/package.json'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! System Linux 4.4.50-v7+
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi/Desktop/alexa-avs-sample-app/samples
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! path /home/pi/Desktop/alexa-avs-sample-app/samples/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pi/Desktop/alexa-avs-sample-app/samples/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.434s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Apr 03 16:43:32 UTC 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (default-cli): Goal requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/home/pi/Desktop/alexa-avs-sample-app/samples). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
./Alexa.sh: line 5: ./wakeWordAgent: Is a directory
```

and 3 terminal window open, but nothing is in them, can't even do Ctrl+C!

And yes, I did make sure it was pointing to the right file location

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Bora

EDIT: I also tried `xterm` but it came out as `bash: xterm: command not found`
.

Comment: You use commands like `cd companionService`; this isn't a good idea because that means that there's one and only one current working directory from which this command will work; if you're in any other directory it will fail. Use the full path to filenames or directories in scripts unless you do a `cd` first.

Comment: Ditto.  Especially if you plan to copy this script to your /usr/bin directory where it can be run anytime from anywhere.  Always use fully-qualified pathnames for everything.  Of course, ~/ is your $HOME directory.  That's always safe to use.

Answer (score 3):

For working out stuff like this it's best to find the simplest possible test that still reproduces the problem; for me that was:

```
$ mkdir dir
$ cat > dir/script
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "I am a script!"
^D
$ chmod +x dir/script
```

Running `xterm -e 'cd dir && ./script; read x'` works fine for me. (Note that I added the `read x` at the end so that it pauses until you hit Enter in that window, otherwise it closes up immediately after running.) You can install xterm by running `sudo apt-get install xterm` and that should work fine for you as well.

The reason it's not working with lxterminal is that, while xterm passes the `-e` argument to a shell to be interpreted, lxterminal appears not to do so, and also appears to be deficient in terms of reporting errors related to this. Having lxterminal run `bash`, and giving the script as a parameter to `bash`, made it work for me

```
lxterm -e 'bash -c "cd dirname && some-command; read x"'
```

Comment: I installed xterm but the same errors were appearing.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command in your raspberry pi terminal

create this file in bin folder or give a `link` of it in one of dir of `$PATH` of `/usr/local/bin`

```
cd ~/bin
```

if not present create it using `mkdir ~/bin`

```
touch my_script_to_open_terminal.sh
```

give executable permission

```
 chmod 755 my_script_to_open_terminal.sh
```

open the above file and write the following code

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.bash_profile 
sudo date -s "20 OCT 2019" # change date
lxterminal -e bash -c "cd ~;bash" &
echo "next command"
lxterminal -e bash -c "cd /any_dir/where_your_script_is_there;sudo ./my_script.sh;bash" &
lxterminal& # working open terminal only current dir 
 # working dir with an open terminal as you want
lxterminal -e bash -c "cd /user/dir/to/open;bash" &
```

close the file and create a link on desktop

```
 ln -s ~/bin/my_script_to_open_terminal.sh ~/Desktop/my_script_to_open_terminal_link
```